# Ajax entre dominios - como fazer?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Preciso fazer um Ajax para um webservice que está em outro dominio, por causa de uma politica de segurança dos navegadores não é possível. É possível fazer isso via JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

Quem vai decidir se a chamada entre domínios será possível é o servidor. Há basicamente duas formas do servidor liberar as chamadas *cross-domain*. JSONP é uma delas, onde o servidor retorna a resposta da chamada envolta em uma chamada de função. Por exemplo, se uma resposta "normal" ao serviço seria a seguinte:

```
{ "nome": "Scooby Doo", "idade": 10 }
```

Se o servidor suporta JSONP, e o cliente (navegador, via ajax) solicitar a resposta via uma função chamada 'minhaFuncao', a resposta seria a seguinte:

```
minhaFuncao({ "nome": "Scooby Doo", "idade": 10 });
```

Com isso, o cliente (aplicação rodando no navegador) pode usar o tag `<script>` (que não tem limitações *cross-domain*) e chamar uma função que é definida na página. As bibliotecas como jquery escondem a maior parte destes detalhes, então a chamada pra aplicação parece ser uma chamada normal.

Então, voltando à sua pergunta original: sim, é possível fazer a chamada entre domínios via JSONP **se o webservice suporta JSONP**. Como mostrado acima, o serviço precisa retornar uma resposta diferente, então a solução não pode ser feita apenas do lado do cliente.

Note que há ainda outras formas de habilitar a chamada *cross-domain* pelos clientes. JSONP suporta apenas chamadas que usam o método HTTP GET - POST, PUT, etc. não são suportados. Para outros métodos, [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) é uma alternativa, e é suportado pela maioria dos navegadores modernos (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE10+). Assim como JSONP, o servidor tem um papel ativo em permitir as chamadas.

Uma outra alternativa, se o servidor não suporta CORS ou JSONP é a utilização de um serviço (web service) que serve como um *proxy*, encaminhando as chamadas do seu cliente pro servidor final. A vantagem é que como o proxy não está rodando em um navegador, ele não tem nenhuma das restrições de *cross-domain*; no entanto, o proxy perde o contexto do cliente (por exemplo, se a aplicação web usa cookies para fazer log-in no serviço, o proxy não terá os cookies e as chamadas deles serão anônimas).